# Расширить функционал шорткода WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У WooCommerce есть готовые шорткоды. При использовании данного шорткода `[products limit="6" columns="3"]` выводится миниатюра, заголовок, цена и кнопка "В корзину".

Подскажите, как можно добавить атрибут, например: `content="true"`, чтобы шорткод выводил краткое описание товара?

В итоге получаем `[products limit="6" columns="3" content="true"]`

[WooCommerce Shortcodes](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/dc7aa3069466f1b7e23fd7ef468760a6a9ddd241/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php#L460-L580)

Answer (score 0):

Непосредственно в шорткоде нет опций по выводу контента. Шорткод в данном случае просто запрос на вывод товаров по определенным условиям.

Подробная документация по шорткоду [products] https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Для управления выводом используйте хуки страницы магазина-архива-категории

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

Например, для вывода описания под заголовком можно переопределить хук вывода заголовка

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

function custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    
     global $product;
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <div itemprop="description">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);
```

Пример для эффекта только на шорткод

```
<?php remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 ); ?>

<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10); ?>

<?php do_shortcode('[products limit="6" columns="3"]'); ?>

<?php remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10); ?>

<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 ); ?>

<?php

function custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    
     global $product;
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <div itemprop="description">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это я знаю, только тут вопрос в том, что описание должно быть не цикле вывода товаров на страницы магазина и архивов, а именно у тех товаров, которые выводятся шорткодом

Comment: @eugene_vandar тогда перед выводов в шаблоне <?php do_shortcode('[products limit="6" columns="3" content="true"]'); ?> наложите нужные фильтры, а после вывода верните обратно все хуки

Comment: @eugene_vandar дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, это при условии если выводить шорткод в коде, но я вывожу в контенте страницы, Elementor, Gutenberg имеют блоки шорткод, ну или же Classic Editor. Думаю проще будет создать кастомный шорткод, хотелось просто кастомизиловать существующий

Comment: @eugene_vandar как вариант создать свой шорткод и вставлять его в elementor, в котором будет выполняться искомый шорткод [products] с нужными хуками

Comment: Так-то оно так, ответ хорошо всё поясняет, но с параметрами шорткода что делать? Где их обрабатывать? Я тоже смотрел код we и не нашёл возможности расширения шорткода. Похоже, только писать свой.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а что меняется в обработке параметров шорткода?

Comment: Дополнительный параметр, что хочет добавить автор вопроса ( content = true) , его где обрабатывать?

Comment: @KAGGDesign я же описал вариант для автора - обернуть в свой шорткод вызов шорткода [products] и уже своем обработчике шорткода отрабатывать нужный параметр.

Comment: Свой шорткод - не совсем то, что он хотел.